# Std::copy and std::ostream_iterator to use overloading function to print values

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

I am wondering how to use std::copy to use overloading operator of my class.
For example to print vector of type int  we can use something like this

```
std::vector<int> vec{ -1, 4, 70, -5, 34, 21, 2, 58, 0 , 34 , 27 , 4 };
std::copy( vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " "));
```

But say I have class Employee  and overloading operator <<

```
class Employee
{

public:
    Employee( const string _name, const string _last, const int _sal ):
        name(_name),
        lastname(_last),
        salary(_sal )
    {

    }
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os,  Employee&obj )
{
    return os << obj.name << " "<< obj.salary;
}

private:
    std::string name;
    std::string lastname;
    int salary;

};
```

Then how would I use std::copy to use ostream_iterator  to print name of employee and salary example

```
 int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee> staff
     {
         {"tim", "sim", 1000 },
         {"dave", "ark", 2000 },
         {"kate", "Greg", 2000 },
         {"miller", "jane", 1000 },
         {"wht", "Up", 2000 }

     };

 std::copy( begin( staff), end(staff), std::ostream_iterator<Employee>( cout, " ")); // How to use this line ???
 return 0;
}
```

When I type above line I got compiler error  **invalid operands to binary expression**

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] as required.

Comment: Thats minimal code which can produce problem. I seriously dont know what more info I can provide.  All I want to do is to use std::copy to print salary and name. I can use for loop for that but I am interested in knowing how to do with std::copy.

Comment: _"Thats minimal code which can produce problem"_ [Really??](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b0006f46eb41dec2)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, sorry mate . I will add int main and return 0 as well. I just ignored it as I thought if i add full code then I might get negative point.

Comment: _"if i add full code then I might get negative point."_ Nope, just the opposite. You should post full but **minimal** code, that exactly reproduces your problem. From your edit, it looks you still didn't get what a [MCVE] is.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Thanks for info. I will keep this in mind for future as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::ostream_iterator::operator=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator%3D) takes its parameter as `const&`. Internally, this will use `operator<<` to output each value into the stream.

But the parameter is `const`, so it can't be passed into your `operator<<`! A `const&` doesn't bind to a `&`. That's why the compiler is complaining. You will have to mark it `const&`:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&os,  const Employee& obj )
{
    return os << obj.name << " "<< obj.salary;
}
```

That's also good practice: You are not going to modify `obj`, so there is no reason why you don't mark it as `const`.